# SSIS Analysis Services

Tags: ssis, parallel-processing, ssas, analysis

I am seeing the same issue - as the link below: Parallel processing not supported on Standard edition of Analysis Services

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/b9b1ad28-9d69-4483-b662-83f507196753?prof=required

I checked my registry settings, under Microsoft SQL Server .. Setup etc

Edition: Enterprise Edition
PatchLevel: 10.0.1600.22
SP: 0
Version: 10.0.1600.22

Is there a fix for this one?

Comment: Please change the title of this question to match the actual question / issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run this through Profiler and can see it running in Parallel.

It must just be a warning / notification.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the RTM version, you should upgrade to a newer version - at least SP1.  Your software is 3 years old and unpatched.

http://www.sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've upgraded now using SP2 - still got same issues. Edition: Enterprise Edition, PatchLevel: 10.2.4000.0, SP: 2,  Version: 10.2.4000.0.

Comment: In SSIS, my Analysis Services Processing Task has a version of: 10.0.1600.22. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Not sure, did you update your workstation components as well?

Comment: I only upgraded to SP2 - no I didn't update any components, how do I do this?

Comment: You would need to run the installer on the machine with the SSIS client tools installed (your workstation).

Comment: okay, yes, that was already done - for Testing purposes SSAS is on the same machine as the SSIS project I'm developing. The Installer comes up with the Shared Features: Integration Services already checked.

Comment: "Analysis Services Processing Task":
- In the editor, I add the required Dimensions with the Process Options as : Process Update
- I then click "Change Settings", in the Processing Order, as soon as I select Parallel the following warning appears, even though I'm using the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server: 
           "Parallel processing not supported on Standard edition of Analysis Services"

Comment: The Installer comes up with the Shared Features: Integration Services already checked - ie this is checked and Disabled, so not sure what I can do further here to upgrade the Integration Services.
What version of this SSIS component should I be on, as I am on:
Analysis Services Processing Task has a version of: 10.0.1600.22
thanks

Comment: That's the same component version I have on my machine.  I would suggest if you can't find an issue to this problem, try processing the cube from the SSAS gui, generate a script and then schedule as a job step.  Might work, depending on what steps are going on around it.

Comment: I've run this through Profiler and can see it running in Parallel. 

It must just be a warning / notification.